# What are recommendable articles comparing existence-and-uniqueness-theorems for partial differential equations?

Tags: analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

A classic type-of-theorem in the theory of partial differential equations are, of course, *existence-and-uniqueness-theorems* (henceforth, *eaut*s for short) for a given class of pde.

**Question.** Do there exist articles in the research literature, preferably with an expository and survey-like character, which *discuss eauts* **as such**, e.g. by restricting to a reasonably small number of classes of pde, stating a good eaut for each of them, and then go on to *compare* said eauts from different perspectives (logic, difficulty of proof, methods necessary for the proof, applicability of the eaut elsewhere, etc)

**Remark.**
I would be particularly interested in works which emphasize *the formal presentation of the pdes in question*, and the **decision problem "Now here we have an eaut $T$; but is it difficult to, and how can we, decide for a given formal presentation of a pde $E$ whether $T$ applies to $E$?"**

Comment: Is your question really related to the model theory and the decision theory?